# Preference - How to prevent duplicate tabs from being opened?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, preference

I like to work in multiple columns when working on a project.

I will often switch back and forth between the columns and open other files using cmd+p.

If one column has the file open already then it will just refocus on that tab (good!). However, if I am in a column where the file isn't opened, instead of switching focus to that column, it will open a new tab and clutter my workspace(bad!).

Is there a setting I can change so I can achieve the desired behavior I described above? Chrome has an extension that can do [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clutter-free-prevent-dupl/iipjdmnoigaobkamfhnojmglcdbnfaaf?hl=en)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a plugin for Sublime text 3 for this as well, it's called **Open in relevant window** and it works just like you just described.

Installation is simple and just like any other ST3 plugin, through package control.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks, from the description it does what i want it to do, but after installing and testing, i still get duplicate tabs

Comment: @c0de I've been using that plugin for quite some time and, for me, it's gotten rid of duplicate tabs, I don't know where it screws up for you

Comment: nope. i've installed the package and restarted sublime text 3, no behavior change.